# Wrong implementation of mysqli?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to use mysqli for the first time because i have some problems with multiple Query's in one php file. for start im just trying to retrieve data from the stored procedure and print it. but it looks like the code get's stuck somewhere it printed 'succesfull localhost' but it never get's to the code under it. The data never get printed neither the failed.

```
    <?php
$link = mysqli_init();
if (!$link) {
    die('mysqli_init failed');
}

if (!mysqli_options($link, MYSQLI_INIT_COMMAND, 'SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0')) {
    die('Setting MYSQLI_INIT_COMMAND failed');
}

if (!mysqli_options($link, MYSQLI_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 5)) {
    die('Setting MYSQLI_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT failed');
}

if (!mysqli_real_connect($link, 'localhost', 'root', '', 'fabiola')) {
    die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
            . mysqli_connect_error());
}

echo 'Success... ' . mysqli_get_host_info($link) . "\n";


//require 'header.php';

$resID = mysqli_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['resID']);
$materialen_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['materialen_id']);
$aantal = mysqli_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['aantal']);
$effectief_gebruikt = mysqli_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['effectief_gebruikt']);
$opmerking = mysqli_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['opmerking']);
$datum_van = $_REQUEST['datum_van'];
$datum_tot = $_REQUEST['datum_tot'];


$sqm = "CALL aantal_besch_mat_van_tot($datum_van,$datum_tot,$materialen_id,$resID)";
//$result = $mysqli->query($sqm) or die('Query Failed!');

/* Select queries return a resultset */
if ($result = $mysqli->query($sqm)) {
    printf("Select returned %d rows.\n", mysqli_num_rows($result));
    /* free result set */
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}else{
    echo 'failed';
}


mysqli_close($link);
```

?>

Comment: Maybe I don't see it, but.. `echo 'Success... ' . mysqli_get_host_info($link) . "\n";` is the only thing you are outputting ( if there are no errors ). So what are you expecting?

Comment: try to enable all warnings and notices first by calling error_reporting(E_ALL); somewhere in the beggining of your php code.

Comment: Im trying to print printf("Select returned %d rows.\n", mysqli_num_rows($result));

Comment: what part of your code prints "successful localhost" ? if you do `$link = mysqli_init();

print_r($link);` - does it print `mysqli Object ( )` ?

Comment: this part is not printing : printf("Select returned %d rows.\n", mysqli_num_rows($result));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is $mysqli set or initialized?

There should be something like:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
```

but I can't see it.

btw it's weird that you're mixing the function calling convention 'mysqli_real_escape_string(...)' with the object-orientated functions '$mysqli->query(...)' I'm not sure it's safe to do both.

Also, you will save yourself a lot of heartache by using the MySQLi prepared statements rather than trying to make all your input safe by hand e.g.

```
$query = "CALL aantal_besch_mat_van_tot(?, ?, ?, ?);";
$statement = $mysqli->prepareStatement($query);
$statement->bind_param('iiii', $datum_van, $datum_tot, $materialen_id, $resID);
$statement->execute();
//get the results.
$statement->close();
$mysqli->close();
```

It's just so much easier, and more secure to use prepared statements (at the cost of a few percent of performance) that really you should almost always use them.